# Run Python Script in Power Bi create a Panda DataSeries of current time so when refreshed the time changes

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I am trying to show how dynamic data from Python can change in Power Bi when published. I am trying to get the current time in a Panda Dataseries as its the only input Power Bi allows. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried this as a test but the data table is empty

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')`
```

Comment: are you publishing this into the powerbi service or embedded if so this would fail, it would be better if you create a calculate calendar table using DAX  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyvhM5eiT0U in regards to your script it should return a power query object.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice, it was to be published. It is just to be used as an example for importing dynamic data from Python and showing that it can work when published. Do you know of other examples that may work?

Comment: depends what you're trying to do, create a caelndar table then a measure that is set to now to only filter for the current day and hours into the day?

Comment: Just show an example with Python. It can be any dataset. I just thought the easiest would be current time and date